# How to declare global static array of strings and const non-POD data in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, qt, global-variables

I need to make constant global array of strings in file "misc.h". I don't really understand how this should be done. If it was just one string, I would have declared it like this:

```cpp
// misc.h
extern const char* str;

// misc.cpp
//static const char* str = "some sring"; invalid because of extern linkage 
const char* str = "some string";
```

If i want an array of strings, first thing that comes to mind is:

```cpp
extern const char* strings[];
```

The size of array is known at compile-time and usually
would have been deduced by the compiler from initializer,
but here the initialization would lie (as of my understandnig) in another compilation unit, misc.cpp (the array is pretty big and i don't want to re-count it's size every time i add features and recompile my code). How should I handle this situation?
**Edit:** all of the strings and everything in this question is immutable and does not need any functionality from standard library.

The second question on the same topic is how should I declare constant hash map (`const QHash`, more specifially) in the same file? I also need it to be global static. I am not building a library, and this hash map servers the core functionality of my application, so making it global static should be appropriate. I know there is `Q_GLOBAL_STATIC` macro, but it is used for preventing data races, and my hash map is read-only by definition. I've heard about inline variables, but I don't really understand them - should I try to dig there? What would be the best way to do declare and use such variable?

Comment: You say "array" but you declared "pointer to array", why?

Comment: `extern const char* strings[];` is valid. The size doesn't need to be given here. You can just do `const char* strings[]={"a"};` in your misc.cpp.

Comment: How about exposing another variable for the size, e.g. `extern int strings_size;`?

Comment: You should declare array getter function in header file instead of `extern` variable declaration. And it would be a good idea to return `::std::span` there. So array size could be deduced from the initializer. On the other hand, creating a global `QHash` object is a terrible idea since it will be prone to SIOF.

Comment: TLDR : not!. Having global variables is not a good design decision in the first place. What you can do however is have compile time constant array of strings by creating a header file containing an `inline constexpr std::array<std::string_view,N> strings {"string1", "string2", ... };`.

Comment: 1. Variables are global, but are hidden in a namespace for better encapsulation.
2. all of the keys and values are known at compile-time, so there should be no risk of SIOF (keys are const char*, values are enum veriants).
3. I don't need to use the size of array in my code, I am just worried about how the compiler would deduce it (so i don't think stdlib here is necesarry). 4. I understand consequences of having mutable global variables, but since everything i have is a bunch of constants, I don't see much of an issue in that

Comment: Namespaces do not hide anything and provide no encapsulation. Risk of SIOF appears when dynamic initialization is involved, so there is no way to avoid it with `QHash` (whether initializers are all constants and enums does not matter).

Comment: `static` in the definition in the first example is wrong. It gives the variable internal linkage while you already gave it external linkage with `extern` earlier. That's not compatible. The compiler ought to complain about linkage mismatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any immutable global constant `c` of type `C` in C++, you can simply write

```
const C c = /*initializer*/;
```

in the header. `const` variables have internal linkage by default. It will be a different `c` in each translation unit and there won't be any redefinition error. (Beware however that this is different in C.)

Even better would be

```
constexpr C c = /*initializer*/;
```

assuming the type `C` supports the constant expression initialization. This guarantees that no initialization will happen at runtime and that the variable can be used in other constant expressions. With just `const` there may be dynamic initialization at runtime, which can potentially lead to issues with initialization order, although that is less of a concern inside a single translation unit than across multiple. (`constexpr` implies `const` on the type.)

In few occasions the type may support constant expression initialization, but not constant destruction. In that case one can still use

```
constinit const C c = /*initializer*/;
```

`constinit` will cause the declaration to fail if constant initialization can't be performed, while still allowing non-constant destruction. (It does not imply `const` on the type though, so that must be added explicitly.)

If constant initialization is not possible and order of initialization a potential concern, a global variable shouldn't be used at all. Instead local `static` variables in a function can be used.

If you need to rely on `c` being the same object in each translation unit, then you can add `inline` to the definition in the header.

---

For an array of strings:

```
constexpr const char* c[] = {"string1", "string2", "string3"};
```

or

```
constexpr std::array c = {"string1", "string2", "string3"};
```

(Or any other variation of declaration syntax for these types. You could also use `std::string`, but that doesn't currently support constant initialization as of C++23. Variations of the two declarations using `std::string_view` are however possible.)

Doing this initialization in the header also has the benefit that every translation unit will automatically know the size of the array. Using `extern` and a definition in a single translation unit would mean that either other translation units don't know the size or that you have to manually enter the correct size in the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to make global **array** of strings in file "misc.h".

You can use pointer to `const char` array. In this method, you don't need to use the `extern` keyword in the definition.

**misc.h**

```
//declaration-----v-------->note the pointer in this example
extern const char *str[];
```

**misc.cpp**

```
//definition, note no need for extern keyword here.
const char *str[] = {"some"," string"};
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/ciI0GtEGk)

---

Also [What are the pros and cons in use of global variables? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-in-use-of-global-variables)